# Star Wars: Possible reference to our Solar System?

Tags: star-wars

Star Wars: Fate of the Jedi: Apocalypse, by Troy Denning, page 183:

> ...But it was the panels between the arches that put a flutter in Raynar's stomach. The images depicted the grandeur of deep space, always with some peculiar twist that seemed unlikely to occur in nature. There was a supernova exploding in only one direction, **a ring of nine planets circling their sun in a single orbital path**, a nebula hanging like a curtain between two star systems...

The paragraph and others go on to narrate Raynar asking about a five planet system with two planets sharing the same local orbit, getting answer from Thuruht, "our work, Five Rocks" (Corellian system), and the book goes on.My question stands for the bolded part.

Comment: There is also the fact that E.T's species is seen briefly in the Galactic Congress

Comment: How does this answer the question? The fact that a few senators from Brodo Asogi show up in the senate does not have anything to do with the book or the passage in question.

Comment: well, _some_ say our system doesn't even have 9 planets, just 8 now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Circling their planets in a single orbital path" would seem to mean they all share the same orbit (i.e. they all orbit the same distance from the central star), which would match the preceding statement that the panels "depicted the grandeur of deep space, **always with some peculiar twist that seemed unlikely to occur in nature**" and the mention of a supernova exploding only in one direction as another example (real-life supernovas explode outward spherically in all radial directions from the center). Since all the planets of *our* solar system orbit at different distances (aside from a brief moment when Pluto's orbit intersects Neptune's), I don't think this was intended to be ours.

Comment: That was my first thought as well. But when the outermost orbit of Corellia is included in the dialogue, one has to wonder if the author differentiated between Corellia's Talus & Trallus and depicting "single orbital path" like each planet in question had their individual orbits, unlike Corellia's Twins.

Comment: I don't understand your point about Talus and Trallus, I'm not particularly familiar with the EU in general, can you explain? When you say "like each planet in question had their individual orbits, unlike Corellia's Twins", do you mean that the "Twins" do orbit at the same radius? It might also help if you quoted the part you summarize as "Raynar asking about a five planet system with two planets sharing the same local orbit" and explained why you think this section indicates they might mean something different by "circling their planets in a single orbital path" than my interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Since the movies have precedence over the books, and the movies make it quite clear that the events we are witnessing took place...

[image]

...it doesn't seem very likely.  I am not aware of any information that would suggest that people from the Galaxy Far Far Away ever traveled a significant distance from their own galaxy, especially to our own galaxy, which is, as the opening crawl says, "far, far away".

The existence of a system with 9 planets is not enough to justify the assertion that the system in question is our own.

Comment: Well, there is one instance where Han Solo and Chewie accidentally crash on Earth after a failed (or rather, blind) hyperspace attempt. But the comic is non-canonnical. For more info, look for "Into The Great Unknown".

Comment: @VerpinZal - I saw a few screenshots of that.  Don't they hang out with Indiana Jones or something like that?

Comment: --spoiler alert--

Indiana Jones finds the corpse of Han Solo, if I recall..

-- spoiler alert --

Comment: @VerpinZal You recall correctly; Chewie becomes the source of the Bigfoot legend, which is what draws Indy to the location

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/94151/2108

Comment: @calccrypto - You got me.  But it is important to note that no one in their right mind would say that ET and Indiana Jones are part of the Star Wars canon.