# Is there a human home planet?

Tags: star-wars

Did all the humans in the *Star Wars* universe originate on a single planet some time in the distant past, or did they originate on different worlds and intermix into one species over millenia?

This is specifically about only humans, not humanoid aliens. I would prefer answers from the main canon or EU canon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there humans in the Star Wars Universe?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4073/why-are-there-humans-in-the-star-wars-universe)

Comment: Yes, Coruscant.

Comment: @RogueJedi similar, but I'm not asking why the humans are there, I'm asking if we know where they come from

Comment: Wasn't there some cancelled story Lucas was workng on linking Star Wars with THX 1138, involving time travel and the like?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Canon

According to the 2015 mobile game "[Star Wars: Uprising](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Uprising)", humanity's homeworld is **Coruscant**. Since this game was made [after May 2014](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/80098/20774) and with the approval of the Lucasfilm Story Group, this information can be considered fully canonical, albeit I rather suspect that retconning it (e.g. *they actually had a different homeworld which people are largely unaware of*) would be trivially easy.

[image]

### Legends

Coruscant tends to be the favoured planet in the Legends EU canon.

> ***Taungs** are warriors first and foremost, **having battled the native Human nations for control of Coruscant** before being driven off and
> forced to flee to the Outer Rim world of Roon, where they remain for
> millennia until the legendary Mandalore the First leads them to
> conquer another world. Taungs rename both the world and themselves in
> his honor, becoming the Mandalorians.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Galaxy at War - RPG Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galaxy_at_War)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[Essential Guide to Planets and Moons](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Guide_to_Planets_and_Moons)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[Marvel Star Wars #84 - Seoul Searching](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_84:_Seoul_Searching) (n.b. Notron is another name for Coruscant according to the [Star Wars: Essential Atlas](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Atlas))</sup></sub>

Comment: That last comic panel seems to say that other worlds claim to be the birthplace of humanity as well, which is interesting.