# Do we know where Human life originated in the Star Wars galaxy?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Assuming that the different species of alien all originated on different worlds around different stars do we know where the "Human" lifeforms that make up the majority of the *Star Wars* films came from originally?

Comment: Related - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4073/why-are-there-humans-in-the-star-wars-universe?rq=1

Comment: An even longer time ago, in a galaxy even far far fartherer away...