# Are there "Light Side places"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

In the Star Wars galaxy, there are places where the Dark Side is strong. It usually manifests as twisted fauna and deranged people. I know about such places thanks to the computer games that take place during the Old Republic (KOTOR, TOR), for example the tombs on Korriban or the temple on Dromund Kaas.

Are there similar places where the Light Side is strong? How come they seem to be much rarer or nonexistent?

Wookieepedia refers to places like this as ["Force nexuses"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_nexus), but it doesn't say much about the Light Side variety.

Comment: Another example of darkness, ... at least if you believe Yoda, ... is the cave on Dagobah. I mention not believing Yoda, because someone sent me this site the other day: http://ammonra.org/skywalkerparadigm/index.html

Comment: (note the ESB/RotJ sections in that site aren't working, but the basic premise is well spelled out on the NH section)

Comment: oh dear - please tell me that site is a parody of all the extremist nutbar theories about government in our world (the New World Order, Illuminati, etc) :p

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure how serious the author of that site is (or satirical), but there is also this question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4070/is-the-rebellion-really-good that broaches similar themes... and from the number of upvotes on that question, I'd say there's a fair number of people who "question the official story".  ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My impression from reading various EU material was that the 'stain' from dark side users was due to the nature of their deaths.

> The Emperor leaves one such stain around Endor where he met his death at the hands of Vader

Also

> It's revealed the cave on Dagobah is the site of the (presumably violent) death of another "Dark Jedi" (early EU didn't use Sith for contemporary dark side users) at the hands of a number of Jedi Knights

Whereas - almost all the light-side deaths we see in the movies, the force users are accepting their fate, and seem to pass on to some other plane (some of them are even able to return as force ghosts).

> Even Vader / Anakin Skywalker can be counted - he overcame his dark side at the end of RotJ, and accepted his death as it came

There is at least one neutral force nexus in the EU - the Valley of the Jedi seems to be a place of great power, and can even instill the force into sensitive beings.

I have yet to come across force nexus that is identified specifically as light-sided, however.

Answer (score 13):

### Yes

According to Doug Chiang, [one of the designers](https://www.starwars.com/news/we-set-the-bar-so-high-doug-chiang-on-designing-rogue-one?cmp=smc%7C756139147&linkId=32763287) for Rogue One, the Jedha temple focuses the good side (presumably the light side) of the Force:

> One of things we landed on early was this idea of a tuning fork - a
>   twin tower kind of look. And it was really interesting, because then
>   that started to give Gareth a lot of ideas like, ‘Well, maybe the
>   structure is built this way because it is like a tuning fork. It’s
>   tuning the dark side in terms of the energy.’ And then we actually
>   carried that even further to Jedha. The Jedha temple, the tower there,
>   mirrors this but on the good side.

As such, it could be considered a “light side place.” Jedha itself is more likely neutrally aligned (owing to the presence of the kyber crystals), but the temple could certainly be called a “light side nexus.”

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Legends material is ok here, as most nexuses are such.

There is the Oasis on Tatooine, a place of great tranquility, of which it is remarked that even the animals feel it and do not quarrel in the place.

Also on Aleen there is a light-side nexus. Orphia or something like that.

The temple on Ilum seems to be a rather powerful light side nexus, and one that the Empire did not destroy even though they took control of it.

Most of the Jedi temples are nexuses, but usually they are dual nexuses; a light side nexus built over a dark side nexus through the meditation of light side adherents, or a light side nexus being tainted by dark side rituals or acts of great violence.

The takeaway for me is that dark side nexuses usually happen due to violence and are created quicker and more easily, where light side nexuses happen usually through slower, tranquil processes such as meditation.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. This is an interesting answer. It would be improved if you could indicate where in legends these places are described.